# Javascript method chaining working but convoluted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to have an item from a list faded out then removed than this:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(2000, function(){this.remove();});
});
```

It works, but seems a bit convoluted. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't really any simpler than that. Maybe you can pass in `this.remove` instead of `function(){ this.remove(); }` but that's about it.

Comment: That's not method chaining! It's just a callback passed to `fadeOut` so when it finishes its job it will call it!

Comment: This is already using jQuery so most of the work is already done for you... I can't really think of anything that would make it much more simple as this is as simple as it gets.

Comment: In this particular case you can shorten it like this: `$(this).fadeOut(2000, this.remove);`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most you can do is probably this:

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(2000, this.remove);
});
```

jQuery already did most of the abstraction for you and there isn't really much you can do to shorten it. Remember this is not code golf - you don't get points for using the shortest code.